# Inno Setup and components stored online

Tags: installation, inno-setup, inno-download-plugin

I'm quite new to Inno Setup and scripting but managed to create own setup with 30 different components to be selected and installed. I would like to add more of them but what's left is simple too big, so I would prefer to convert my whole setup to be like an online installer.

Downloaded and installed InnoTools Downloader, tested some examples, but it's probably too difficult to me. I would need a good example of Inno Setup/InnoTools Downloader script with a few components to be DL online, so I can analyse and learn how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the `setup.iss` example script that comes with Inno.  This is the script for Inno itself, and includes some download functionality.

Currently I think it uses ISXDL rather than ITDownload, but the same basic structure applies to both.  Compare it with the example script included with ITDownload.

Answer (score 1):

So I have followed instructions on this page: https://code.google.com/p/inno-download-plugin/plugin/

They have great examples there.